# Regex formula - cannot recognize formula

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write pattern to recognize formula IF form string.

e.g. string

```
[@param_6@]  @IF(@param_5@==null;@param_5@;@IF(1==1;@param_2@;@param_4@)@)@ - @param_3@ - <@IF(@parameter_tag2@ == null;@param_4@;@param_5@)@>
```

I want to obtain this result

```
1. Match: @IF(@param_5@==null;@param_5@;@IF(1==1;@param_2@;@param_4@)@)@
2. Match: @IF(@parameter_tag2@ == null;@param_4@;@param_5@)@
```

My pattern look like:

```
@IF\(.*\;.*\;.*\)@
```

But regex return me wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?s)@IF\((?>(?!@IF\(|\)@).|(?<o>)@IF\(|(?<-o>)\)@)*\)@
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9Ayzc/2). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` equivalent, `.` now matches LF chars, too
- `@IF\(` - a `@IF(` string
- `(?>(?!@IF\(|\)@).|(?<o>)@IF\(|(?<-o>)\)@)*`  - zero or more repetitions of

  - `(?!@IF\(|\)@).|` - any char that does not start a `@IF(` or `)@` char sequence
  - `(?<o>)@IF\(|` - a `@IF(` substring and a value is pushed on to the "o" group stack, or
  - `(?<-o>)\)@` - a `)@` string and a value is popped from the "o" group stack
- `\)@` - a `)@` string